# React / Redux Topic: Conditional Rendering based on Store State

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, conditional-rendering

Preface:

- This is an authentication mechanism in my project.
- I am refactoring from using Contexts to Redux to control state

The Redux store holds a "isLogged" as a boolean as a part of the state. Upon successful login (the user submits the form with the correct email and password), an axios response validates the user and the client dispatches an action with a state change. The **state change happens successfully**, based on what I see using the redux dev tools extension.

The Problem:

I have a navbar component that conditionally renders links public and private components based on the isLogged state. It just doesn't rerender when the store state is updated, so currently the user is not able to see an updated navbar, even though the state change happens as it should.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: provide some code so someone can debug it and tell where is the problem.

Comment: You'll probably need to connect the Navbar component to redux, could you share the initial state and the Navbar code

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem.

I had to access the store state via the useSelector hook from "react-redux". It seems that when I was trying to just grab the state earlier using the store.getState() method and storing it in a variable and passed down through props, the function components were not listening to the updates.